# C# - Selecting a Column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I am creating a football roster using C# and Visual Studio.  I've created a DataGridView calling dgvPlayer.

[DGV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yFs1.png)

My goal is to select a box on dgvPlayer and have the information be copied into a Name textbox, Team textbox, etc.  I'm really just confused as to the how to identify that a certain box is being selected.  Please help!

```
dgvPlayer.Columns["Name"].DefaultCellStyle.Format
```

Comment: you can simply use `txtholder.text = dgname.currentrow.cell["Name"].value.ToString()` it can return all the value of that ceratain row base on what you need. also you can insert this code in `cellclick event` or in any event that can handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this that adds some validation against selecting the header row of the grid view

```
private void dgvPlayer_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            txtTextBox.Text = dgvPlayer.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToString();          
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to do, you will have to add a handler for the CellClick event. The event will fire everytime the user make a click on some cell, then you will have to put your own business logic there. You can do something like this:

```
dgvPlayer.CellClick += dgvPlayer_CellClick;

private void dgvPlayer_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     yourTextBox.Text = dgvPlayer.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToString();
}
```